# Ререндер происходит после клика в другую область

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
 const messagesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

   switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NEW_MESSAGE_BODY:
        state.newMessageBody = action.body;
        return state;
    case SEND_MESSAGE: {
        let body = state.newMessageBody;
        state.newMessageBody = '';
        state.messages.push({ id: 5, message: body });
        return state;
    }
    default:
        return state;
}
```

};

```
export const updateNewMessageBodyCreator = (body) => {
return {
    type: UPDATE_NEW_MESSAGE_BODY,
    body: body
};
```

};

```
export const sendMessageCreator = () => {
return {
    type: SEND_MESSAGE
};
```

};

```
Дальше контейнерная компонента 

 import { updateNewMessageBodyCreator, sendMessageCreator } from '../../../../../redux/messages-reducer';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';


  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

return {
    newMessageBody: state.newMessageBody
};
```

};

```
   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

return {
    updateNewMessageBody: (body) => {
        dispatch(updateNewMessageBodyCreator(body));
    },
    sendMessage: () => {
        dispatch(sendMessageCreator());
    }
};
```

};

```
  const NewMessageAreaContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewMessageArea);

   export default NewMessageAreaContainer;


И презентационная 

 const NewMessageArea = (props) => {

      let newMessageBody = props.newMessageBody;

       console.log('newMessageBody:', props.newMessageBody);

      let onSendMessageClick = () => {
    props.sendMessage();
};

      let onNewMessageChange = (e) => {
    const body = e.target.value;
    props.updateNewMessageBody(body);
};

      return (
    <div className={cl.areaWrapper}>
        <input className={cl.input}
            value={newMessageBody}
            onChange={onNewMessageChange}
            type="text"
            placeholder='Enter your message' />
        <button onClick={onSendMessageClick} className={cl.button}>Send</button>
    </div>
);
```

};

```
  export default NewMessageArea;

Вот тут console.log('newMessageBody:', props.newMessageBody);  undefined,  проблема тут, но как ее решить я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста
```